# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jets3t/service/S3ServiceException error from saveAsTextFile when trying to write to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, rdd

When trying to write an RDD to S3

```
entries.map(lambda x: json.dumps(x)).saveAsTextFile("S3Path")
```

It's returning

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2678.saveAsTextFile.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jets3t/service/S3ServiceException
```

Entries is an RDD with this format:

```
[{'computation_source': 'fdna_glue_job', 'computation_datetime': '2022-07-13T13:00:00Z', 'id': 'a1', 'id_type': 'ddna_id', 'alternative_ids': [], 'attributes': {'is_registered_user': False, 'is_fanhub_user': False, 'has_downloaded_app': False, 'newsletter_signup': False, 'declared_sports': 'N/A', 'declared_nocs': 'N/A', 'declared_athletes': 'N/A'}, 'genes': {}, 'is_valid': True, 'errors': []}, {'computation_source': 'fdna_glue_job', 'computation_datetime': '2022-07-13T13:00:00Z', 'id': 'a2', 'id_type': 'anonymous_id', 'alternative_ids': [], 'attributes': {'is_registered_user': False, 'is_fanhub_user': False, 'has_downloaded_app': False, 'newsletter_signup': False, 'declared_sports': 'N/A', 'declared_nocs': 'N/A', 'declared_athletes': 'N/A'}, 'genes': {}, 'is_valid': True, 'errors': []}, {'computation_source': 'fdna_glue_job', 'computation_datetime': '2022-07-13T13:00:00Z', 'id': 'a3', 'id_type': 'ddna_id', 'alternative_ids': [], 'attributes': {'is_registered_user': False, 'is_fanhub_user': False, 'has_downloaded_app': False, 'newsletter_signup': False, 'declared_sports': 'N/A', 'declared_nocs': 'N/A', 'declared_athletes': 'N/A'}, 'genes': {}, 'is_valid': True, 'errors': []}]
```

The issue seems to be when trying to save to S3, since I ran the same script to save locally and it ran fine. What confuses me is we have other Glue jobs that save data the same way and are running fine. Not sure what to do, but here is how we set up our spark in the glue job:

```
    logger.info("Configuring Spark")
    conf = (
        SparkConf()
        .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")
        .set("spark.rpc.message.maxSize", "256")
    )
    for k, v in spark_worker_var_dict.items():
        conf.set("spark.executorEnv." + k, v)

    logger.info("Getting Spark Context")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.maxRetries", "20")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "mapred.output.committer.class",
        "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter",
    )

    logger.info("Getting Glue Context")
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session

    logger.info("Creating AWS Job")
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(resolved_args["JOB_NAME"], resolved_args)
```

Full traceback:

2022-07-13 13:51:26,900 ERROR [main] glueexceptionanalysis.GlueExceptionAnalysisListener (Logging.scala:logError(9)): [Glue Exception Analysis {"Event":"GlueETLJobExceptionEvent","Timestamp":1657720286894,"Failure Reason":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/gene_batch_attributes_registered_users_aa8f149820d61d5fb60bc902c889cc5e", line 117, in \n    resolved_args=resolved_args,\n  File "/tmp/fdnautils-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/fdnautils/pipeline.py", line 18, in compute_gene\n    result = gene_function(**{k.lower(): v for k, v in resolved_args.items()})\n  File "/tmp/gene_batch_attributes_registered_users_aa8f149820d61d5fb60bc902c889cc5e", line 93, in main\n    write_gene_output(df, is_backfill, GENE_NAME, environment)\n  File "/tmp/fdnautils-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/fdnautils/aws.py", line 1082, in write_gene_output\n    logger.info(f"VALID ENTRIES PREVIEW: {valid_entries.take(3)}")\n  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1360, in take\n    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)\n  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 1069, in runJob\n    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)\n  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**\n    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)\n  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco\n    return f(*a, **kw)\n  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value\n    format(target_id, ".", name), value)\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 36, 172.21.36.62, executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)\n\tat scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)\n\nDriver stacktrace:\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)\n\tat scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)\n\tat scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)\n","Stack Trace":[{"Declaring Class":"get_return_value","Method Name":"format(target_id, ".", name), value)","File Name":"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py","Line Number":328},{"Declaring Class":"deco","Method Name":"return f(*a, **kw)","File Name":"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py","Line Number":63},{"Declaring Class":"**call**","Method Name":"answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)","File Name":"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py","Line Number":1257},{"Declaring Class":"runJob","Method Name":"sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)","File Name":"/opt
2022-07-13 13:51:26,900 ERROR [main] glueexceptionanalysis.GlueExceptionAnalysisListener (Logging.scala:logError(9)): [Glue Exception Analysis] {"Event":"GlueETLJobExceptionEvent","Timestamp":1657720286894,"Failure Reason":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n File "/tmp/gene_batch_attributes_registered_users_aa8f149820d61d5fb60bc902c889cc5e", line 117, in \n resolved_args=resolved_args,\n File "/tmp/fdnautils-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/fdnautils/pipeline.py", line 18, in compute_gene\n result = gene_function(**{k.lower(): v for k, v in resolved_args.items()})\n File "/tmp/gene_batch_attributes_registered_users_aa8f149820d61d5fb60bc902c889cc5e", line 93, in main\n write_gene_output(df, is_backfill, GENE_NAME, environment)\n File "/tmp/fdnautils-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/fdnautils/aws.py", line 1082, in write_gene_output\n logger.info(f"VALID ENTRIES PREVIEW: {valid_entries.take(3)}")\n File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1360, in take\n res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)\n File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 1069, in runJob\n sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)\n File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**\n answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)\n File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco\n return f(*a, **kw)\n File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value\n format(target_id, ".", name), value)\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 36, 172.21.36.62, executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)\n\tat scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)\n\nDriver stacktrace:\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)\n\tat scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)\n\tat scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)\n\tat org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)\n\tat org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeWriter.write(UnsafeWriter.java:109)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1124)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1130)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)\n\tat scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)\n\tat scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)\n\tat org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonUDFRunner.scala:50)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:345)\n\tat org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:194)\n","Stack Trace":[{"Declaring Class":"get_return_value","Method Name":"format(target_id, ".", name), value)","File Name":"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py","Line Number":328},{"Declaring Class":"deco","Method Name":"return f(*a, **kw)","File Name":"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py","Line Number":63},{"Declaring Class":"**call**","Method Name":"answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)","File Name":"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py","Line Number":1257},{"Declaring Class":"runJob","Method Name":"sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)","File Name":"/opt

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that when querying the data from Redshift into a Spark DF, there were nulls which were affecting the data types. Then when trying to call `.show()`, was getting the error.